# Getting an unexpected NameError in pycassaShell when invoking one function from another

Tags: python, cassandra, pycassa

I'm playing with [pycassaShell](http://pycassa.github.com/pycassa/assorted/pycassa_shell.html) (as part of the [Cassandra](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/GettingStarted) and the [Twissandra](https://github.com/twissandra/twissandra/) tutorial).
When trying to add two functions inside the shell, and call one from the other I get an error that the Name is not recognized.

This is probably something very simple, but I did not find how to do this.

The pycassaShell looks like:

```
In [3]: def aaa(): print 5
In [4]: aaa()
5

In [5]: def bbb(): aaa()

In [6]: bbb()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
...
NameError: global name 'aaa' is not defined
```

Comment: Can you include the elided output in the traceback (assuming that there is some)?  There might be something useful there and I don't have Cassandra/pycassa set up at the moment, so I can't check for myself.

Comment: Works perfectly in pure IPython.

Comment: Works fine in pure python as well

Comment: Had similar problems myself with django shell. Looks like it may be a bug in ipyrhon: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/2532

Comment: I agree: It afects my django shell and pycassaShell - each of which use ipython

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with the way Pycassa is embedding IPython.  This is [the same problem](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/62) @Benjamin White references regarding Django's IPython use.  Django [fixed the bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17078) by [accepting a pull request from an IPython core dev](https://github.com/django/django/pull/512).

I took the liberty to [file an issue with Pycassa](https://github.com/pycassa/pycassa/issues/193).  Hopefully they'll be able to investigate why a similar fix won't work for them.

Answer (score 0):

This is odd. I don't know why it is happening, but try this:

```
def aaa(): print 5

def bbb():
    global aaa
    aaa()
```

Comment: could you run `dir()` and tell us the output? In python it should say `['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'aaa', 'bbb']`.

Comment: @eran can you please run dir()?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are using Python 3? If you are, visit http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html for the list of changes.

It worked both in IPython and regular python v2.7.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
def aaa(self): print 5 
def bbb(): self.aaa
```

That's what I do when I get Name Errors...